# A pythonic way to find all indexes of one sequence in the other one?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given two lists `f=['a','b','c','d']` and `g=['a','c']`, I can produce `[0,2]=indexes(f,g)` with

```
def indexes(f,g):
    return [f.index(x) for x in g]
```

is there a better way?

**Motivation**:
For a `numpy` matrix `X`, I want to extract some columns, so I want to replace `pd.DataFrame(X,columns=f)[g].values` with `X[:,indexes(f,g)]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) after  [`np.1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) to get the intersecting indices:

```
np.where(np.in1d(f,g))
(array([0, 2], dtype=int64),)
```